# Repeated Problems while setting up Spring Archetype

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I could not find an answer to this question elsewhere.

I'm trying to set up a Virtual Machine to learn spring,wicket and hibernate. I began with [this](http://blog.iprofs.nl/2011/02/15/a-maven-quickstart-on-wicket-spring-and-hibernate/) maven-archetype and used it like so :

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=nl.iprofs -DarchetypeArtifactId=wicket-spring-hibernate-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.3 -DarchetypeRepository=http://www.iprofs.nl/repository/ -DinteractiveMode=false -DgroupId=me.sandbox -DartifactId=swh
cd swh
mvn install 
mvn eclipse:eclipse
mvn jetty:run
```

Jetty starts the demoproject and it is accessible as it should be.

Then I imported the project into the latest STS (SpringSourceToolsuite). But when I deploy the application, I get this Error:

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
```

I just don't understand it. I'm new to spring and haven't used maven a lot, but I was under the impression that maven would have resolved dependencies (such as the above) automatically :/

In my .classpath-file, I find (besides many others) these entries:

```
<classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.5.8/slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar" sourcepath="M2_REPO/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.5.8/slf4j-api-1.5.8-sources.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.4.2/slf4j-log4j12-1.4.2.jar" sourcepath="M2_REPO/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.4.2/slf4j-log4j12-1.4.2-sources.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/log4j/log4j/1.2.14/log4j-1.2.14.jar" sourcepath="M2_REPO/log4j/log4j/1.2.14/log4j-1.2.14-sources.jar"/>
```

It seemed that M2_REPO is undefined. I tried symlinking the folder .m2/repository from my user-folder to the project folder and even added the environment-variable M2_REPO pointing to the same location. *All* the referenced files are in the folder structure. But I still get the same error and there are still warnings from the Classpath Dependency Validator for the maven-jars.

If any of this helps:

I am running this on a 64Bit XUbuntu inside an oracle-vm.
I installed maven2 and openjdk-7-jdk from the repositories, Springsource Toolsuite .sh-installer 64Bit 2.9.2 from the official site.

I'm very confused since I never thought it would be that hard to set up a simple demo-archetype. I guess I have made a simple/naive beginners-mistake. But I have no clue. Please help me.

If you need any more information please let me know.

Comment: Which purpose does the mvn eclipse:eclipse has?

Answer (score 0):

If M2_REPO is undefined you normally should get a warning in eclipse/STS. To be sure that the variable is available you can go to `Preferences > Java > Build path > Classpath variables`. If you have no variable M2_REPO defined here you can add it with a path to `<path>/.m2/repository`

I can't say much about the maven-archetype you are using. But maybe you should have a look into [Spring roo](http://www.springsource.org/spring-roo/) which can help you a lot creating a new Spring project (creating configuration files, adding dependencies to pom.xml etc.).
Creating a new Spring project using hibernate with roo is basically writing 2 commands:

```
project --topLevelPackage com.company.project
jpa setup --provider HIBERNATE --database MYSQL
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have M2 pluggin setup for eclipse , you can set the M2_HOME there.
If you dont have m2 pluggin installed for eclipse  then just add your M2 repository to the classpath